# Can I automatically refresh my Azure SQL table from a Power BI Dataflow Entity?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database, entity, dataflow

Can I refresh my SQL Azure table with a power BI entity through a set gateway connection ? Actually, I am in the course of automatically refreshing an azure SQL table through a power BI Dataflow entity. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Its not quite clear what your question is about, you want to refresh a sql table using power bi or, refresh the dataflow from azure sql db

Comment: You don't need a gateway with an Azure SQL Database

Comment: Hi Jonee. Thank you for the response. Indeed my main concern is to be able to update an Azure sql table from an existing Power BI dataflow with entities created from a different data source. In other word, Using power BI dataflows as an ETL tool, with updates from one Azure sql table to another. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible, data flows is only used to extract data from Azure SQL server, you'll need data factory, SSIS, to move data from one SQL table to another or manage them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a gateway with the Azure SQL database.

But make sure you have set the Azure [SQL Database firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule) to allow the Power Bi access the SQL database.

When you connect to the Azure SQL database, you can not specify the getaway, but pleas click the bellow option:

[image]

For PowerBI data flow, you could reference this document: [Using incremental refresh with Power BI dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-incremental-refresh). This feature also can help achieve auto refresh the Azure SQL table data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon Yue. Thank you for the insightful response. I currently have a gateway set just as described. My main concern is to be able to update an Azure sql table from an existing dataflow with entities created from a different data source. In other word, Using power BI dataflows as an ETL tool, with updates from one Azure sql table to another. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: @Nelson_z No, we can't. Actually, you purpose is auto update the Azure SQL database data, not just refresh it. You need to using other  tools such as Data Factory achieve that.

Comment: @Nelson_z  I suggest you post another question to ask how to auto update the SQL database table with other data source. Maybe you can learn from [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). In the end, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.